# EAAccessory problem

Tags: iphone

I have developed code using EAAccessory , and its work fine...

But when i disconnect EAAccessory, my application got exception like an error....I want to show an alert , while disconnecting EAAccessory....

I am using this line of code in my app

- (void)accessoryDidDisconnect:(EAAccessory *)accessory;

But this event is not fired ..When i disconnect my accessory....

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance..........

Comment: Is this a Made for iPod program accessory?  Does the accessory have one or more supported protocols?  You can't just use any accessory with the 3.0 custom accessory support.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Deepak mentioned, you also need to do a

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
```

and unregisterForLocalNotifications sometime before your app exits.

Answer (score 1):

To get the notification from the device when your device gets disconnected, you need to register method with "addObserver" in default notification.

```
[notificationCenter addObserver: self  selector: @selector (accessoryDidConnect:)   name: EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification object: nil];

[notificationCenter addObserver: self  selector: @selector (accessoryDidDisconnect:)   name: EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3.0.2, I use this.....

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.accessoryDidConnect),name:  NSNotification.Name.EAAccessoryDidConnect, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.accessoryDidDisconnect),name: NSNotification.Name.EAAccessoryDidDisconnect, object: nil)


func accessoryDidConnect() {

    print("Connected Device")
}

func accessoryDidDisconnect() {

    print("Device disconnected")
}
```